# Initiating a service by dialing a phone Number

Tags: android, android-intent, service

My question is, is there any way i can initiate a service (start a service) by dialing a specific number in phone dialer. 
for example if i dial 1234 in phone dialer and an application starts or a service starts with it. if there is any way do let me know. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job fine :

https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/create-a-secret-doorway-to-your-app/

It uses the `android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE` intent.